# Extract multiple fields same named fields using xmllint

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmllint

I've got an XML file with a lot of media fields. A piece of example XML is:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Item 1</name>
        <mediaList>
            <media>
                <name>Name 1</name>
                <URL><![CDATA[http://example.com/image1.jpg]]></URL>
            </media>
            <media>
                <name>Name 2</name>
                <URL><![CDATA[http://example.com/image2.jpg]]></URL>
            </media>
        </mediaList>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Item 2</name>
        <mediaList>
            <media>
                <name>Name 3</name>
                <URL><![CDATA[http://example.com/image3.jpg]]></URL>
            </media>
            <media>
                <name>Name 4</name>
                <URL><![CDATA[http://example.com/image4.jpg]]></URL>
            </media>
        </mediaList>
    </item>
</root>
```

All items are built in the same way. Using XMLLint with XPath, I'm trying to get a list of all URLs. However, so far, I haven't found the best way to go about it yet. Some of the ways I've tried it are:

`xmllint --xpath "string(/root/item/mediaList/URL)" file.xml >> log.txt`

This one returns a nice URL, but stops after the first item (giving me only 1 image)

`xmllint --xpath "/root/item/mediaList/URL" file.xml >> log.txt`

This gives me all items, but everything is on the same line, and is shown as `<URL><![CDATA[http://example.com/image.jpg]]></URL>` for each item.

`xmllint --xpath "/root/item/mediaList/URL/text()" file.xml >> log.txt`

This comes closest, but still returns the `<![CDATA[]]>` tags around it, and again all in one line.

I've also tried looping through the items, but this was very slow, and didn't work as it should.

The result I'm aiming for is a txt file with all images below eachother, like so:

```
http://example.com/image1.jpg
http://example.com/image2.jpg
http://example.com/image3.jpg
http://example.com/image4.jpg
```

Comment: The `--nocdata` option extracts the text from each CDATA node. I'm not sure how to get each URL on a separate line, though.

Comment: Thanks! Good one. One less problem to think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xmllint` doesn't support the `string(...)` for multiple XPath matches. (Therefore it shows only the 1st result).

You can use `xmlstarlet` like:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /root/item/mediaList/media/URL -v . -n file.xml
```

and it produces

```
http://example.com/image1.jpg
http://example.com/image2.jpg
http://example.com/image3.jpg
http://example.com/image4.jpg
```

or also perl (with the installed [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) module) as:

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -E 'say $_->to_literal for XML::LibXML->load_xml(location=>q{file.xml})->findnodes(q{/root/item/mediaList/media/URL})'
```

also produces same result as above.

Comment: The `xmlstarlet` option solved it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change a parser, in W3C Document:

> Each character within a CDATA section is treated as character data.
>   Thus, <![CDATA[<]]> in the source document will treated the same as
>   <. Both will result in a single < character in a text node in the
>   tree. Thus, a CDATA section is treated as if the <![CDATA[ and ]]>
>   were removed and every occurrence of < and & were replaced by < and
>   & respectively.

CDATA will be removed automatically, I test it in python:

```
tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
tree.xpath('//URL/text()')
```

out:

```
['http://example.com/image1.jpg',
 'http://example.com/image2.jpg',
 'http://example.com/image3.jpg',
 'http://example.com/image4.jpg']
```

Your XPath is correct.